In Angular 18 after migrating to the new build system I got an error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵcmp')
After migrating to the new build system. Using the command:
ng update @angular/cli --name use-application-builder

When I try to redirect on a route with lazyLoading module I got the error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵcmp')
    at getComponentDef (core.mjs:2462:10)
    at extractDirectiveDef (core.mjs:2355:10)
    at core.mjs:2524:96
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at core.mjs:2524:85
    at createTView (core.mjs:11384:59)
    at getOrCreateComponentTView (core.mjs:11333:24)
    at addComponentLogic (core.mjs:12057:17)
    at instantiateAllDirectives (core.mjs:11867:5)
    at createDirectivesInstances (core.mjs:11298:3)

I expect the error gone
UPD: I localized the problem.
Inside one of my lazy-loading routes I have a component with await import:
async showConfirmModal(option: MfaOption): Promise<void> {
    const isEnable = option.status === MfaStatus.INACTIVE;
    const module = await import('@portalLib/_components/mfa/mfa-modal/mfa-modal.component');
    this.modalService.showEntityModal<MfaModalComponent, Partial<MfaModalComponent>>({
      nzContent: module.MfaModalComponent,
      nzData: {
        option: option,
        userId: this.userId,
        email: this.email,
        isEnable: isEnable,
        successCallback: () => {
          option.status = isEnable ? MfaStatus.ACTIVE : MfaStatus.INACTIVE;
          this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        },
      },
    });
  }

Removing await import fixes the error.

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz or github repo where the issue happens!

There is a section on the new build system page that mentions a known issue with lazy modules. Perhaps that's what is causing the issue.
https://angular.dev/tools/cli/build-system-migration#order-dependent-side-effectful-imports-in-lazy-modules

@NarenMurali Sorry, but I have a large code base, so I think I can't reproduce it easily.

@VitaliiLitkevich You might be mixing angular standalone and modular way of initializations that might be why you are getting this issue. Try checking that

@HarisAli Yes I saw it, but the explanation isn't clear for me, and I don't know how to fix it. The section mentions that there is an open issue in esbuild: https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/399 it was open on Sep 20, 2020 and still open

@NarenMurali All my components are standalone and I don't have any my own NgModules. Of course I import some modules in my comnents like: ReactiveFormsModule. And some modules in my main.ts:  JwtModule, ToastrModule

@VitaliiLitkevich Just a suggestion, do you have components in routing that are not standalone and not in any declarations, that will also give you this error!
